# Azure Web App Bot, analytics blade gone. Discontinued?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-application-insights, azure-bot-service

In the Bot Management section of a Web App Bot in Azure, there used to be an analytics blade with usage information of the bot. Just the level of depth needed for my reporting purposes.
Last month, it was still there, this month it is missing.

**Does someone know if the analytics blade was discontinued of moved?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Engineering is aware and currently working on it. There should be a release next week.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/1948